# CSRF anti forgery tokens in jester

Tags: security, nim-lang, jester

In nim the `jester` module does web API servicing, which I'm grateful for, but do we have support of cross site anti forgery tokens ? (against CSRF attacks)
like ASP.net provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is a request to [add support for sessions](https://github.com/dom96/jester/issues/97), but it's still open.